# CPLEX Optimization Studio GUI on Mac

Tags: user-interface, optimization, cplex

I have installed IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio on my Mac but when I run cplex I do not get the same interface as shown in the demo in IBM web site (https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-ilog-cplex/purchase#product-header-top)
 Attached photo shows the interface I get on Mac
May I know if I can get the same GUI as shown in the demo on Mac or it works only on Windows. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the CPLEX OPL IDE is not on MacOS. But as said at [in this message](https://twitter.com/AlexFleischer1/status/884298031075659776) this will change.

In the meantime, you may use a Windows emulator on Mac. See [this message](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=d8581395-8dbe-4485-92a2-cddf95a46507&ps=25).